# Can I make an OS X ESD (or other USB drive) read-only?

Tags: macos, disk-utility, external-disk, permission

I have a USB Flash drive onto which I've used Disk Utility to restore the Mac OS X Install ESD:

[image: Mac OS X Install ESD Finder Info window]

Is there a way I can make the result read-only, in order offer it at lease some semblance of protection from accidental change?

I assume (but don't know for sure) that I cannot make the raw disk itself read-only, so higher levels of protection are okay, but the lower the better.

Comment: Because I was impressed by this answer, I tried it.  Unfortunately, while it still boots, the filesystem itself was still writable. http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/24120/21050

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I have tried is using Sharing & Permissions to set rights to `Read only` for myself, like so:

[image: Sharing & Permissions section of Mac OS X Install ESD Info window with all rights set to Read only]

This prevents some writes:

```
megaweapon:Mac OS X Install ESD matt$ touch foo
touch: foo: Permission denied
```

but if I try to make modifications through the Finder, I'm prompted for my password for administrative access.

Unfortunately, this is not a hard defense against write access.  To accomplish this, a USB stick with a write lock switch (hard to find) or perhaps an SD card in a reader might work.

Answer (score 0):

Use Disk Utility to convert the image to a read only type image rather than a read/write type image.

Open Disk Utility, click the "Convert" button, chose your disk image file, change "Image Format" to "read-only" and press "Save."

Disk Utility will make a new copy of the image file that can't be modified.

Just make sure you label them so they're easy to tell apart.

Comment: I'm not clear how this would apply to a USB drive.